# Avoid Shell 22 error code with shell -e -x

Tags: shell

I need to be able to handle exit code non-zero and use `set -x -e`

I have the following shell script (/bin/bash) in a Debian 9 system:

```
set -e -x
install_agent="$(/usr/share/get_value/install_agent || false)"
if [[ "${install_agent}" == 'true' ]]; then
   echo 'Agent successfully deployed.'
else
   echo 'Metrics will not be installed.'
   return 0
```

I use `install_agent` to check or not if that value was passed by user.
If it is not passed (/usr/share/get_value/install_agent) returns execution code 22 which causes my shell script to exit due to set -x -e being defined, if it is defined returns 0 and the value. 
How to handle this situation and keep the set -x -e. I think my question is also is there like try/exception option in shell.

Comment: `|| false` -> `|| true` maybe (I usually spell it `|| :`)?

Comment: Does `if /usr/share/get_value/install_agent; then ...` work?

Comment: You might consider going through [the exercises in BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), or reviewing the list of incompatibilities between different implementations at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, before deciding that using `set -e` is a good idea. The people describing it as an equivalent to perl's strict mode are generally not the same people who are actually writing quality reference material on bash (folks in the latter set generally understand just how problematic `set -e`'s definition is).

Comment: ...which is to say, no, shell *doesn't* have any form of exception handling, and trying to treat `set -e` as if it were such a thing is a route to pain and suffering. The right way to write quality code in bash is the same way you write quality code in Go or C -- with *explicit* error handling, and code reviewers trained to look for it.